# Which free compiler implements C++14 new features?

Tags: compiling, software-rec, c++

I want to use the new features of C++14 on Linux. Which free compiler grants these features?

Comment: I guess you mean which "C++" compiler...

Comment: Just to be clear: the C++14 standard has been withdrawn (ie. is outdated).  The current standard is C++17.  The features you want haven't been "new" for a while now.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb: "Withdrawn" is a very strong word. The overwhelming majority of systems out there will just be migrating _to_ C++14, if not C++11. Many will still be legacy C++98/03. C++14 does not cease to exist just because a newer alternative is available on cutting-edge toolchains. ISO has not "withdrawn" it, although from a pedantic point of view one might argue that C++17 supersedes it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Withdrawn" is a very strong word but also a correct one. https://www.iso.org/standard/64029.html

Answer (score 21):

According to the standards support pages for [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) and [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), you can use gcc >= 5.0 or clang >= 3.4. Most C++14 support was added in 4.9 for gcc, but a few features did not make it in until 5.0.

Answer (score 5):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) has a full feature-support matrix.

Clang and Cray(?) have full ++14 support.

GCC 5, Sun/Oracle C++ 5.15, and MSVC 19.10 support ++14 with the exception of "clarifying memory allocation".

GCC 7 has support for all ++17 features except "Standardization of Parallelism TS".

Answer (score -1):

Default `gcc` compilers of Debian distro implements `c++14`.
If your have RedHat distro try using `devtoolset-6-gcc` or `devtoolset-6-gcc-c++`